# Chrome extension gives error, when i try to click on function

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that does the following, Trys to add a link to google chrome storage so that I can then get that link, and add it to my html. When I was doing some debugging I noticed that when I clicked on my button add link, that has an href of `javascript:getStorage`.

***Full HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Open URL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="width: 128px; height: 128px;">
    <h2><b>Open URL</b></h2>
    <h3><a href="javascript:setStorage()" target="_blank">Add Link<br></a></h3>
    <h3><a href="https://www.ph4.org/r.php" target="_blank">Random<br></a></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**ERROR**

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html", "popup.js"
  ],

  "name": "UrlManager",
  "description": "Quickly open urls.",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "storage", 
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Open a URL"
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

function setStorage() {
    var value = prompt("Whats your link")
    
    storage.set({key: value}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });
}

 
function getStorage() {
    storage.get(['key'], function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    });
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this?